# How do we prove that $a^{\log{b}} = b^{\log{a}}$ for $a > 1$ and $b > 1$?

Tags: logarithms

I have tried using the change of base formula, but can't quite complete the equality:

$$
a^{\log{b}} \\
a^{\frac{\log_a{b}}{\log_a{a}}}
$$

How do I get the base of the exponent to be b?

Comment: Hello David:  I really thank you for posting this problem to get great answers, and I am up-voting accordingly!  The result of this question was used (and linked) in the [linked Stack Exchange Math Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876064/algebraically-simplify-n-left-frac-left5-right-log-5-left2-rig),  "Algebraically Simplify $n =\left( \frac{ \left(5\right)^{\log 5}} { \left(2 \right)^{\log 2}} \right) ^{ \frac{1} {\log 2-\log 5 } } = \frac{1}{10} $"   Once again, thank you for your usesful question and all the useful answers from below!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $x = e^{\log x}$

\begin{align*}
a^{\log b} = \left(e^{\log a}\right) ^{\log b} = e^{\log a \log b} = e^{\log b \log a} = \left(e^{\log b}\right)^{\log a} = b^{\log a}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Let $x=a^{\log b}$ and $y=b^{\log a}$. Then $\log x= \log a$. $\log b= \log y$. So, $x=y$.

Answer (score 2):

Let (capital) $B$ be the base of the logarithms.  Then
$$
a^{\log_B b} = \Big(B^{\log_B a}\Big)^{\log_B b} = B^{(\log_B a)(\log_B b)},
$$
and that is clearly symmetric in $a$ and $b$.  Or you could just go on from there:
$$
\cdots= \Big(B^{\log_B b}\Big)^{\log_B a} = b^{\log_B a}.
$$