# Solving $(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have seen this equation from a link named [Asisten and German Academy](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=402127092184544), (it is a  video of Facebook) where there is a complicate solution (I invite to watch it) for

$$(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5}$$

I have adopted, instead, this approach:
$$(2)^{\log 2}(n)^{\log 2}=(5)^{\log 5}(n)^{\log 5} \iff 2n^{\log 2}=5n^{\log 5}$$

After

$$\frac{n^{\log 2}}{n^{\log 5}}=\frac 52 \iff n^{(\log 2-\log 5)}=\frac 52$$

$$\log(n^{(\log 2-\log 5)})= \log 5-\log 2 $$

$$(\log 2-\log 5)\log n=\log 5-\log 2  \iff \log n =-1$$

Hence $$e^{\log n}=e^{-1}\implies n=\frac 1e$$

Now I have seen the solution is $n=1/10$.

Is it different my solution why my base is $e$ and not $10$? Generally I have seen that $\log=\log_{10}$. In Italy we used often $\log=\log_e$. I yet thought with the old notation that $\operatorname{Log}=\log_{10}.$ I not adopted often $\ln$ where the base is neperian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regardless of what base you are using, it is **not true** that both
$$ 2^{\log(2)} = 2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 5^{\log(5)} = 5. $$
It is certainly true that $2^{\log_2(2)} = 2$, but the notation $\log$, without a subscript, does not mean "choose whatever base you like and go with it," it typically denotes a *specific* base.

In mathematics, $\log$ typically means the *natural logarithm*,<sup>[1]</sup> which has base $\mathrm{e}$.  Under that assumption,
$$ 2^{\log(2)} \approx 1.617 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 5^{\log(5)} \approx 13.334. $$
If $\log$ denotes the *common logarithm*, which as base $10$, then
$$ 2^{\log(2)} \approx 1.232 \qquad\text{and}\qquad 5^{\log(5)} \approx 3.080. $$

In any event, assuming that $\log$ is the natural logarithm,
$$\begin{align}
&(2n)^{\log(2)} = (5n)^{\log(5)} \\
&\qquad\iff \frac{2^{\log(2)}}{5^{\log(5)}} = \frac{n^{\log(5)}}{n^{\log(2)}} \\
&\qquad\iff\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\log(2)^2}}{\mathrm{e}^{\log(5)^2}} = \frac{n^{\log(5)}}{n^{\log(2)}} \label{eq1}\tag{*} \\
&\qquad\iff \mathrm{e}^{\log(2)^2 - \log(5)^2} = n^{\log(5)-\log(2)} \\
&\qquad\iff \log(2)^2 - \log(5)^2 = \log(n) \left( \log(5)-\log(2) \right) \\
&\qquad\iff \log(n) = \frac{\log(2)^2 - \log(5)^2}{\log(5)-\log(2)} = -\left( \log(2)+\log(5)\right) = -\log(10) \\
&\qquad\iff n = \mathrm{e}^{-\log(10)} = \frac{1}{10}.
\end{align}$$

At (\ref{eq1}), I am using the fact that for any positive real number $a$, we can write
$$ a = \exp(\log(a)) = \mathrm{e}^{\log(a)}, $$
since the exponential and logarithm are inverse functions to each other.  This implies that, for exmaple,
$$ 2^{\log(2)}
= \left( \mathrm{e}^{\log(2)} \right)^{\log(2)}
= \mathrm{e}^{\log(2)\cdot \log(2)}
= \mathrm{e}^{\log(2)^2}. $$

Note that the choice of the natural logarithm is irrelevant here.  Replacing the natural logarithm with the logarithm with base $b$ will have the effect of replacing every occurrence of $\mathrm{e}$ with $b$ in the above computation, but this will not change the result.

---

[1] The question asks about "neperian" logarithms.  This term does not exist in English, though it probably refers to the [Napierian logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napierian_logarithm) (also spelled "Naperian"), named for John Napier, the Scottish mathematician responsible for working out large tables of logarithm ("Napier's bones").  The Napierian logarithm is the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 4):

As already pointed out in the comments and in Xander's answer, your calculation is wrong because $2^{\log_b 2} = 2$ and $5^{\log_b 5} = 5$ do not hold simultaneously for any base $b$.

I would argue as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
&(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5} \\
\iff &\log 2 (\log 2 + \log n) = \log 5 (\log 5 + \log n) \\
\iff &\log n = - \frac{(\log 5)^2 - (\log 2)^2}{\log 5 - \log 2} = -\log(10)
= \log \frac{1}{10} \\
\iff &n = \frac{1}{10}  \, .
\end{align}
$$

This calculation is valid no matter what the base of the logarithm is.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $a^{\log a} = e^{\log^2 a}$ then

$$(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5} $$

$$2^{\log 2}n^{\log 2}=5^{\log 5}n^{\log 5}$$

$$e^{\log^2 2+\log n \log 2}=e^{\log^2 5+\log n \log 5}$$

and since $e^x$ is striclty monotonic, the latter is equivalent to

$$\log^2 2+\log n \log 2=\log^2 5+\log n \log 5$$

$$\log n = \frac{\log^2 2-\log^2 5}{\log 5 -\log 2}=-\log 10 \iff n=\frac1{10}$$

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply take the logarithm of both sides:

$(2n)^{\log 2} = (5n)^{log 5} \iff$
$\log 2 \log(2n) = \log 5 \log(5n)$

This can be elaborated and simplified:

$\log 2 (\log 2 + \log n) = \log 5 (\log 5 + \log n)$
$\log n = -(\log 2 + \log 5) = -\log 10 \iff n=\frac{1}{10}$

Because:
$a(a+x) = b(b+x)$
$a^2-b^2 = (b-a)x$
$x=-(a+b)$

Answer (score 0):

If we let $n=\frac k{10}$, then
$$
\begin{align}
&(2n)^{\log 2}=(5n)^{\log 5} \\
\iff 
&(\tfrac k5)^{\log2}=(\tfrac k2)^{\log5}\\
\iff 
&5^{-\log2}k^{\log2}=2^{-\log5}k^{\log5}\\
\stackrel{(*)}{\iff}
&k^{\log2}=k^{\log5}\\
\iff 
&k^{\log5-\log2}=1\\
\iff
&k=1 \;\text{and}\; n=\frac1{10}
\end{align}
$$

$(*)$ By taking $\log$ of both sides,
$$5^{-\log2}=2^{-\log5}\iff -\log5\log2=-\log2\log5.$$

Answer (score -5):

The question Equation 1 (is repeated here to easier reference) is:

$$
\left(2 n \right)^{\log 2} = \left( 5 n \right)^{\log 5}
\tag{Eq. 1}$$
Then,
$$\begin{align*}
\left(2 \right)^{\log 2}\left(n \right)^{\log 2} &= \left( 5 \right)^{\log 5} \left( n \right)^{\log 5}
\tag{Eq. 2}\\
\frac{\left(n \right)^{\log 2}}{ \left( n \right)^{\log 5}} 
&= 
\frac{\left( 5 \right)^{\log 5}} { \left(2 \right)^{\log 2}}
\tag{Eq. 3}\\
n^{\log 2-\log 5 }
&= 
\frac{\displaystyle \left( 5 \right)^{\log 5}} 
{\displaystyle  \left(2 \right)^{\log 2}}
\tag{Eq. 4}
\end{align*}$$
Finally, the result is given in Equation 5 as:
$$
\boxed{
n = 
\left(
\frac{\displaystyle \left( 5 \right)^{\log 5}} { \displaystyle \left(2 \right)^{\log 2}}
\right)
^{
 \frac{\displaystyle 1}
 { \displaystyle \log 2 - \log 5 }
 } = \frac{1}{10}
}\tag{Eq. 5a}$$

Also, since all of the symbolic algebraic operation was independent of the base $\log_b$, the same result holds independent of base $b$ so long that $b>0$ and $b \ne 1$ ([with algebraic steps referenced in this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876685/how-can-solving-left-2n-right-left-log-b-2-right-left-5n-right/4880297#4880297)):

$$
\boxed{
n = 
\left(
\frac{\displaystyle \left( 5 \right)^{\log_b 5}} { \displaystyle \left(2 \right)^{\log_b 2}}
\right)
^{
 \frac{\displaystyle 1}
 { \displaystyle \log_b 2 - \log_b 5 }
 } = \frac{1}{10}
}\tag{Eq. 5b}$$

###### Simplification of Equation 5 to Get to $n=\frac{1}{10}$

From Equation 5, it can be rewritten as follows:
$$
n=\left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log 2} (5)^{-\log 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log 2-\log 5}
 \right)
$$
$$
n=
\left(
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log 5} (5)^{-\log 2}} 
  \right)^
  \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log 2-\log 5}
  \right)
\right)
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2*5)^{\log 2 -\log 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log 2-\log 5}
 \right)$$
$$
\tag{Eq. 6}
$$
For the professionals, the symbolic representation of $0.1$ is sufficient to be derived using standard symbolic math manipulation techniques. Especially the identities "$a^n*b^n=(a*b)^n$" , "$(a^n)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a$" for "$a \ge 0$", and
[$a^{\left(\log b \right)} = b^{\left(\log a \right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660200/how-do-we-prove-that-a-logb-b-loga-for-a-1-and-b-1) are helpful in the above simplifications.

In particular, the simplifications and Equations 6 together with the identity [$a^{\left(\log b\right)} = b^{\left(\log a \right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/660200/how-do-we-prove-that-a-logb-b-loga-for-a-1-and-b-1) imply that

$$ 
\left(\frac{\displaystyle (5)^{\log 2} }
             {\displaystyle (2)^{\log 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log 2-\log 5}
 \right)
=\left({\displaystyle 1 }\right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log 2-\log 5}
 \right)=1
\tag{Eqs. 7}$$
$$
n=\left({\displaystyle 1 }\right)
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1 }
             {\displaystyle (2*5)^{\log 2 -\log 5}} 
  \right)^
 \left(\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle \log 2-\log 5}
 \right)
\tag{Eq. 8}
$$

And finally, referencing the identity $\left(a^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a$ for $a>0$ and $n \ne 0$, Equation 8 leads to the desired solution.

Also, more step-to-step simplification steps are given this [reference, "Algebraically Simplify $n =\left( \frac{ \left(5\right)^{\log 5}} { \left(2 \right)^{\log 2}} \right) ^{ \frac{1} {\log 2-\log 5 } } = \frac{1}{10}\text{"}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4876064/algebraically-simplify-n-left-frac-left5-right-log-5-left2-rig).

With both either reference link or use of the identity $\left(a^n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=a$ options, immediately the decimal simplification and answer from Equation 8 becomes apparent:
$$
\boxed{
n=
\left({\displaystyle 1}\right)
\left( \frac{\displaystyle 1} {\displaystyle 2} \right)
\left( \frac{\displaystyle 1} {\displaystyle 5} \right)
=\frac{\displaystyle 1}{\displaystyle 10}
}
\tag{Eqs. 9}$$

###### Symbolic to Decimal Verification

This result can also easily be verified with a scientific calculator (done already below), so it is definitely correct:
[image: Scientific Calculator Verification of the Result]
Also with the [Wolfram Online Symbolic Calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%29Power%5B5%2C%5C%2840%29log%205%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29Power%5B2%2C%5C%2840%29log%202%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%29log%202%5C%2841%29%20-%20%5C%2840%29log%205%5C%2841%29%5D%5C%2841%29%5D):
[image: Online Wolfram Symbolic Calculator Result]
The decimal result is the same, that $n=0.1$:
[image: Symbolic Exact Result and Decimal Representation]

Comment: Simpler: rewrite  your  $\rm\color{#c00}{base}$  expression as below, with $\,\ell_n := \log n$

$$\large (\color{#c00}{e^{\large -(\ell_2^2-\ell_5^2)}})^{\Large \frac{1}{\ell_2-\ell_5}}\! =\:\! e^{\large -(\ell_2+\ell_5)}= 2^{-1}5^{-1}\qquad\qquad$$

Comment: @Bill Dubuque:  the symbolic answer is independent of base $\log_b$;  I am not sure how $e$ would generalize the result to almost any base $\log_b$ that the author implies in his question details.